# Why is the follower count not working on django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have been trying to implement a follow/unfollow system on django in which a user can follow other users and the user can also be followed, in the user's profile there is a following count which displays how many people the user is following and a follower count which is supposed to display how many followers the user has just like in instagram. Everything is working good except for the follower count which doesn't counting the followers. for doing this follower count, I used signals but it doesnt work. How can I fix this problem?

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True, default='default.png')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1, null=True)
    connection = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    follower = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    following = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followed")
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="follower")

    @classmethod
    def follow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.add(another_account)
        print("followed")

    @classmethod
    def unfollow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.remove(another_account)
        print("unfollowed")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

views.py

```
def profile(request, username=None):
    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if username:
        post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        profile_bio = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        is_following = Following.objects.filter(user=request.user, followed=user)
        following_obj = Following.objects.get(user=user)
        follower = following_obj.follower.count()
        following = following_obj.followed.count()

    else:
        post_owner = request.user
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        profile_bio = Profile.objetcs.filter(user=request.user)
        
    args1 = {
        'post_owner': post_owner,
        'user_posts': user_posts,
        'follower': follower,
        'following': following,
        'connection': is_following,
        'profile_bio': profile_bio,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)

def follow(request, username):
    main_user = request.user
    to_follow = User.objects.get(username=username)
    following = Following.objects.filter(user = main_user, followed = to_follow)
    is_following = True if following else False 


    if is_following:
        Following.unfollow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = False
    else:
        Following.follow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = True
    resp = {
        'following': is_following,
    }

    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender = Following.followed.through) # which list is changed
def add_follower(sender, instance, action, reverse, pk_set, **kwargs):
    followed_users = [] # list of users main (logged ) user have followed
    logged_user = User.objects.get(username = instance) # user who followed other users
    for i in pk_set:
        user = User.objects.get(pk = i)
        following_obj = Following.objects.get(user = user)
        followed_users.append(following_obj)

    if action == "pre_add":
        for i in followed_users:
            i.follower.add(logged_user)
            i.save()

    if action == "pre_remove":
        for i in followed_users:
            i.follower.remove(logged_user)
            i.save()
```

profile.html

```
{% if connection and not request.user == post_owner %}
  <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' post_owner.username %}">Unfollow</a>
{% elif not connection and not request.user == post_owner %}
  <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' post_owner.username %}">Follow</a>
{% endif %}
<div class="header-item">
  {{follower}}
</div>
<div class="header-item">
  {{following}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

why creating another field for the followers? you can get the followers count and users from the same Following table without any need for followers field.

your following model should only contain user, followed
you can get the followers by using

```
following.objects.filter(followed=request.user)
```

Comment: Hey Isaam! I just tried changing `follower = following_obj.follower.count()` with `follower = Following.objects.filter(followed=request.user)`  and adding this to the html `{{ follower.count }}`. Also I removed followers field from following model and it is still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting 0 as result or null or something else, what's the error please?

Comment: Hey I realized that the error was that the signals.py file was not being recognized by django so now I fixed that but instead of getting that following count not popping up, the buttons are not working. The follow button is not following the user. How can this be solved?

Comment: 1. make sure the requested user has followers
2. try replacing the relationship in the following class (followed field) from ManyToManyField to one to OneToOneField

Comment: when using a OneToOneField, I get an error on signals.py which says `File "C:\Users\USER\startup\gstartup\accounts\signals.py", line 8, in <module>
    @receiver(m2m_changed, sender = Following.followed.through) # which list is changed
AttributeError: 'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'through'`

Comment: I can add followers to a user directly from the admin page and later if you  check the profile you can see the number of followers the user has. But the error is that the buttons are not working correctly and the text insidde the buttons doesnt change meaning that when a button is pressed there is no work done.

Comment: yes then your problem is just in the following button, make sure it's adding record into the database when the followed user is unfollowed and delete it if he already following him.

Comment: How can I check if a record is being added to the database? I have been doing that checking the admin page but it looks like nothing is being added because the buttons dont work. Can I achieve this without using the signals.py file?